# Axis scale displays a wrong value

Tags: c#, rounding, zedgraph

Within ZedGraph you can draw an XY graph easily. Let's use default scale for X axis and a custom scale (0 to 10, major step 2.5, minor step 1) for Y, then redraw the graph:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = 0;
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = 10;
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 2.5;
    zedGraphControl1.GraphPane.YAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
    zedGraphControl1.AxisChange();
    zedGraphControl1.Invalidate();
}
```

Which will display this:

[image]

As you can see, `3` and `8` are `2.5` and `7.5` displayed in the wrong format. Here's how ZedGraph decide of the format to use:

```
internal void SetScaleMag(double min, double max, double step)
{
    // set the scale magnitude if required
    if (this._magAuto)
    {
        // Find the optimal scale display multiple
        double minMag = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(this._min)));
        double maxMag = Math.Floor(Math.Log10(Math.Abs(this._max)));

        double mag = Math.Max(maxMag, minMag);

        // Do not use scale multiples for magnitudes below 4
        if (Math.Abs(mag) <= 3)
        {
            mag = 0;
        }

        // Use a power of 10 that is a multiple of 3 (engineering scale)
        this._mag = (int)(Math.Floor(mag / 3.0) * 3.0);
    }

    // Calculate the appropriate number of dec places to display if required
    if (this._formatAuto)
    {
        int numDec = 0 - (int)(Math.Floor(Math.Log10(this._majorStep)) - this._mag);
        if (numDec < 0)
        {
            numDec = 0;
        }

        this._format = "f" + numDec.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Which, here, leads to `f0`. Obviously this is not correct. I could just add 1 to `numDec` but this would display useless information for XAxis (0,20;0.40...)

I know that if I use values like `10/3d` as major step I will *never* be able to lose information but I would prefer to display 6.7 instead of 7 (reduce the error).

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but `(int)7.5 => 7` and `Convert.ToInt32(7.5) => 8`. Casting truncates and Convert rounds.

Comment: If `this._mag` was 1, then you'd get the right result.  Is there a way of changing that that makes sense?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein see edit

Comment: Ok.  First, that's weird, because they're using `this._mag` inside the `this._formatAuto` if block when it's only set if `this._magAuto` is true.  Three ideas jump to mind: you can try defaulting `this._mag` to 1, and maybe it will work, though I don't know what effect that will have on all possible axis scales.  Or you can say "1-10 is kind of a special case, since the `_magAuto` section is much more concerned about multiples of 1000.  I can just add some special case code into the `_formatAuto` block."  Or, you could just turn off auto formatting, and there must be a way to set it manually.